# webserver is shut down when Apache/AirFlow docker containers are started from local machine

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, airflow

I am trying to set up a development environment for Apache/AirFlow on MacBook with macOS 10.14.x.

I have installed docker, virtualbox and created virtual machine and created containers with web_server, worker, scheduler and redis, postgres.

I run :

```
  docker-compose up -d
```

But, when I visited http://localhost:8080, I got:

```
  This page isn’t working 
  localhost didn’t send any data.
  ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

In the docker-compose log file, I found:

```
 [mwebserver_1 [INFO] Parent changed, shutting down: <Worker 34>
 [mwebserver_1 [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 34)
 [mwebserver_1 {{cli.py:815}} ERROR - No response from gunicorn master within 120 seconds
 [mwebserver_1 {{cli.py:816}} ERROR - Shutting down webserver
```

I am not sure what the problem could be.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your docker-compose.yml and any other files you use to run the containers? You mention you installed virtualbox and created a virtual machine: what is that for?

Comment: @Mihal The virtual machine is created to host the containers of docker. The containers provide services of AirFlow.

Comment: I'm quite sure you don't need that. Docker for Mac takes care of that setup. In any case you missed the most important part of my comment: without the files that you use to run the containers it is difficult that you will get an answer...

Answer (score 0):

After start the docker container's.
Try to run `docker exec -it NAME_OF_CONTAINER /bin/bash`. After that you're gonna into container bash and you can run `airflow webserver`.